# Remove warning : invalidAbsoluteTypeName in pointcut

Tags: warnings, aspectj

I am using LoadTime weaving.
My aspect have been tested and are perfectly working.
I have several project in my workspace and i'm trying to clear some warning just to keep the "real one"

This code give me : [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName] Warning and i can't clear it with @SuppressAjWarnings

```
   pointcut somePointcutName():
            call(*someMethod(..)) &&
            !adviceexecution();
```

So i'm wondering if there is a way to clear those

Thank alots!

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is clear enough. If you need more information just ask.

Comment: I am willing to help, but I need more information. Please extend your question by package, class and method names (full signatures, please). No wonder drgn could not help you like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I played around and I guess I know what happened there: Whatever kind of type signature you have in your `call` pointcut, it seems you used an absolute one, e.g.

`* MyClass.doIt(..)`,

but you have not imported the class and thus cannot access it like that. So you either need

`import com.foobar.my.package.MyClass`

in your aspect or

`* *..MyClass.doIt(..)`

in your pointcut. I guess the Xlint warning is a bit cryptic, but basically that is what it means.

Comment: This side project have been kinda put on the ice since it is working and i am just trying to clear it (Remove warning) The problem is i am not sure i can import those. Those class that i put a pointcut are in jar that i don't own. I am basically hijacking the code i don't own to generate an XML file that i can use later in my own code. This is the reason why i use the loadtime weaving. Also, I had to use jdcompiler to be able to know the class/function to pointcut around. I will still try your solution. I will keep you updated. Thank for your time

Comment: Why should you be unable to import something you want to intercept? But anyway, I provided an alternative approach with the joker for the (not imported) package name. So either way you can solve your problem which is just a bug in your aspect code. Edit: Well, with LTW it might not be a bug, but a just the fact that your stand-alone aspect project cannot see a class name before LTW is applied. So you either need to live with the warning or use the joker, as I said.

Comment: I am sorry it took me a while to answer you. Your solution is exactly what i was looking for. I have no more warning and the aspect are still able to catch the right function call with LTW. Thank you for your time.